# How to run streamus app from terminal

Tags: bash, chromium, scripts, xdotool

I use [Streamus](https://streamus.com/) to stream music from you tube. I want to know whether streamus can be started from terminal itself. I have asked this question in main software site and the author recommended to use xdotool for it. I have installed xdotool (`sudo apt-get install xdotool`) and also able to successfully open the app.

I have mainly two problem

1. Reloading the app
2. Playing from the app

The problem is after the app opens it just shows blank screen. I have to use `ctrl+r` to reload the app, to automate it i used xdotool. This is my script.

```
 /usr/bin/chromium-browser --disable-gpu --enable-offline-auto-reload --enable-offline-auto-reload-visible-only --app=chrome-extension://jbnkffmindojffecdhbbmekbmkkfpmjd/foreground.html & xdotool key ctrl+r
```

But it seems xdotools is not working and its not reloading the app? And also can you help me with playing songs from the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR** The script can not work because that shortcut will be sent to the active window, and that's not `chromium-browser` with `Streamus`.

---

#### This is your *reload* `xdotool` command:

```
xdotool search --limit 1 --name "^Streamus$" | xargs -I {} xdotool windowactivate --sync {} key ctrl+r
```

The complete command in your case is:

```
/usr/bin/chromium-browser --disable-gpu --enable-offline-auto-reload --enable-offline-auto-reload-visible-only --app=chrome-extension://jbnkffmindojffecdhbbmekbmkkfpmjd/foreground.html & xdotool search --limit 1 --name "^Streamus$" | xargs -I {} xdotool windowactivate --sync {} key ctrl+r
```

The execution of the shortcut can be somewhat delayed with `sleep 1`:

```
/usr/bin/chromium-browser --disable-gpu --enable-offline-auto-reload --enable-offline-auto-reload-visible-only --app=chrome-extension://jbnkffmindojffecdhbbmekbmkkfpmjd/foreground.html & sleep 1; xdotool search --limit 1 --name "^Streamus$"| xargs -I {} xdotool windowactivate --sync {} key ctrl+r
```

---

#### This is your *play/pause* `xdotool` command:

```
xdotool search --limit 1 --name "^Streamus$" | xargs -I {} xdotool windowactivate --sync {} key alt+z
```

---

#### A sample script:

To start Streamus, reload and "press" play

```
#!/bin/bash

# Start Streamus
/usr/bin/chromium-browser --disable-gpu --enable-offline-auto-reload --enable-offline-auto-reload-visible-only --app=chrome-extension://jbnkffmindojffecdhbbmekbmkkfpmjd/foreground.html &

# Wait three seconds to finish the previous command
sleep 3

WID=$(xdotool search --limit 1 --name "^Streamus$")

# Refresh the page
xdotool windowactivate --sync "$WID" key ctrl+r

# Wait three seconds to update the page (Ctrl+R).
sleep 3

# "Press" Play
xdotool windowactivate --sync "$WID" key alt+z
```

---

#### Explanation:

- `xdotool search --limit 1 --name "^Streamus$"`

  - `search`

    Search for windows with titles, names, or classes with a regular expression pattern.
  - `limit N`

    Stop searching after finding N matching windows. Specifying a limit will help speed up your search if you only want a few results.
  - `--name`

    Match against the window name. This is the same string that is displayed in the window titlebar.
- `xargs -I {} xdotool windowactivate --sync {} key ctrl+r`

  - `xargs -I {}`

    Build and execute the command `xdotool`
  - `xdotool windowactivate --sync {} key ctrl+r`

    - `windowactivate`

      Activate the window.
    - `sync`

      After sending the window activation, wait until the window is actually activated.
    - `{}`

      `xargs` replaces `{}` with the window id
    - `key ctrl+r`

      sends the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>

Comment: Thanks for this nice explanation to the answer. I would have upvoted but need 15 more reputation. I am new to xdotool and it helps me understand the tool. But how to play streamus? because it just reload and show the song list. We need to click the play button . can it be also be automated using xdotool?

Comment: What is the shortcut for Play/Pause?

Comment: I have customized it to Alt+Z

Comment: Me too, but keyboard shortcuts do not seem to be working in Streamus.

Comment: initially i had the same problem then i changed it to `global` then back to `in chrome` now its working.. So it seems reload only works sometimes any idea whats happening

Comment: No, no idea, here it always works. Did you open multiple windows with the same name?

Comment: no, i always close a streamus  app and start a new one and its not a big issue because it happens only sometimes. Have you succeeded in playing streamus using keyword shortcuts

Comment: I have updated my answer

Comment: The sample script is not reloading the streamus showing this error `Error of failed request:  BadWindow (invalid Window parameter)
  Major opcode of failed request:  3 (X_GetWindowAttributes)
  Resource id in failed request:  0x0
  Serial number of failed request:  22
  Current serial number in output stream:  23
`

Comment: if this helps; I added this command at the last of sample script `echo "windowid: $WID"` as i believe you are passing windows ID but result is just blank `windowid: ` and the above error msg

Comment: Has the Streamus window the title `Streamus` or is there a Streamus window if you start the script?

Comment: Hey thanks for the hint. I have found out the reason why its not reloading. You guessed right it was due to the title of the window. During the initial start of streamus it shows **untititled** instead of **Streamus**. So i added `sleep 3` before `WID=$(xdotool search --limit 1 --name "^Streamus$")` it solved my problem.  Basically now i have 2 sleep command in the script :).. Once more thank you

Comment: Glad to hear that =)

Comment: I have also  linked your answer in the streamus github development site. :) nice meeting you AB

Comment: sorry for causing this inconvenience but I have this minor problem. If i freshly rebooted and logged into my system . Then open your script for streamus without opening `chromium` or the streamus app then the script showing same error and blank wid. So if i have to run your script i have to first open `chromium` or the app first and then execute your script. Do you have this problem?

Comment: My new problem in the above script has been explained fully here (with pictures) in this question http://askubuntu.com/q/629585/414116 . please check that out

Comment: I will do that. Later :)