# Script with xdotool not working properly on a fresh reboot

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, xdotool

I want to run [streamus](https://streamus.com/) (chrome app) to stream youtube from terminal and asked a question relating to that in this same [SE](https://askubuntu.com/questions/628734/how-to-run-streamus-app-from-terminal). I also got a wonderful answer and a script for my problem. But that script has one minor problem. this is the script which helps to run and play streamus from terminal.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Start Streamu


/usr/bin/chromium-browser --disable-gpu --enable-offline-auto-reload --enable-offline-auto-reload-visible-only --app=chrome-extension://jbnkffmindojffecdhbbmekbmkkfpmjd/foreground.html &
sleep 3

    ACT=$(xdotool getactivewindow getwindowname)
    WID=$(xdotool search --limit 1 --name "^Streamus$")
    # Refresh the page


    xdotool windowactivate --sync "$WID" key ctrl+r
    # Wait three seconds to update the page (Ctrl+R).
    sleep 3

    # "Press" Play
    xdotool windowactivate --sync "$WID" key alt+z

    echo "windowid: $WID active window: $ACT"
```

As i believe the problem is caused by the title i added this  `echo "windowid: $WID active window: $ACT"` code  to monitor what was happening in the script.

When we freshly reboot and log into the system and execute the above script with out opening the **streamus app**. It will open the streamus app but will not play it. this is the result

```
X Error of failed request:  BadWindow (invalid Window parameter)
  Major opcode of failed request:  3 (X_GetWindowAttributes)
  Resource id in failed request:  0x0
  Serial number of failed request:  22
  Current serial number in output stream:  23
X Error of failed request:  BadWindow (invalid Window parameter)
  Major opcode of failed request:  3 (X_GetWindowAttributes)
  Resource id in failed request:  0x0
  Serial number of failed request:  22
  Current serial number in output stream:  23

windowid:  active window: Miko@Miko-Notebook-PC: ~/Abraca
```

this is how the streamus app looks
[image]

But when i close that window and again exectue the script I am able to open and play the streamus app.

```
windowid: 82781573 active window: Streamus
```

How can i execute the script without those errors?

*Alt+Z is my custom shortcut for play command in streamus*

Comment: Apart from the message, does it work as expected?

Comment: @JacobVlijm No it doesnt work..  I have updated my question with the picture of non working app

Comment: I am not a bash specialist (!), but my guess would be that it is a timing issue .  The timing of the first or second `sleep 3` might have to be made "smart" (you can try setting it to 10 e.g.). I think it would be best to ping `A.B.`, since he knwos the script.

Comment: @JacobVlijm I had the same thought and tried for 10 seconds but still its not working. one thing i have noted is that streamus app will open after only the sleep command .any way i will ping A.B and ask for his hellp

Comment: I have tested your script and the output is: `windowid: 33554580 active window: ~/tmp/streamu`. I have started in a terminal and the terminal title is  `~/tmp/streamu`

Comment: As you start the script exactly?

Comment: @A.B. this is how i start my script `cd Abraca; ./stream.sh` and still its showing the same error. I am having this problem only after freshly rebooted system. Do you have tried the script after a fresh reboot? can you provide some kind of validation say; if the title is not **Streamus** don’t execute the script else try once more?